# changing users google map marker and saving to local storage

Tags: google-maps, drop-down-menu, local-storage, google-maps-markers

Ok, what i'm trying to achieve is the User will have the option to change there Marker icon with a dropdown menu.
Once they have selected the Icon image i than want it to be saved to the local storage.

here is what i have tried but no luck, i'm not sure if its on the right path or i could do it a totally different way. The local storage is working fine just not able to change the image of the marker.

**google map var i'm using for my marker**

```
var url = 'images/user_marker.png'
```

**local storage**

```
 $('select[name=icon]').val(item);

    $('select[name=icon]').change(function() {
       window.localStorage.setItem('icon', $(this).val());
    });
```

**Drop Down menu**

```
<select name="icon" class="dropdownselect" >
  <option value="images/one_marker.png">Marker 1</option>
  <option value="images/two_marker.png">Marker 2</option>
  <option value="images/three_marker.png">Marker 3</option>
</select>

 $(document).ready(function(e) {
     $('.dropdownselect').change(function(){
  $('url')[0].src = this.value;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not working because you are not declaring the value of the selected option. Change the option tags to include [value](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) to something like this:

```
<option value="images/one_marker.png">Marker One</option>
```

an then try again. I think it should work.

Comment: not to sure how i would go about changing the marker image, I think the Local Storage is working fine.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at these?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers